# datatable search issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I am using `jquery datatable` to display a report in the application. Using the default search the datatable is providing. The search works for most of the scenarios. But I have problems searching on some words.

Figured out that the content between the `<td>` tags are taken as text. So if I search on the word `add`, all rows are shown. This is because the first column has the work `add` as a class attribute. Same is the case with `href`, `get`, `id`, `progress` etc.

```
<tr class="odd">
   <td class=""><a href="#" class="add" onclick="getById(68)">68</a></td>
   <td class="">friw678</td>
   <td class="">windows</td>
   <td class="">
      <span title="Bangalore">Bangal..</span>
      <p>Bangalore</p>
   </td>
   <td class=" sorting_1">
      <span title="6/6/2014 1:02:52 PM">6/6/2014 1..</span>
      <p>6/6/2014 1:02:52 PM</p>
   </td>
   <td class="">
      <div class="progressBarBlueComplete  ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="100">
         <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left ui-corner-right" style="display: block; width: 100%;"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="">
      <span title="COMPLETED">COMPLE..</span>
      <p>COMPLETED</p>
   </td>
   <td class="">sha5</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to only consider the text inside the inner tag also. (Instead of considering the inner tags.) So that if a search on the word `href` search result is empty.

The datatable used is https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can specify datatable's filtering behavior globally, or for each column.
If I understand correctly, removing the html tags from the content of your table cells would be good for you. You can do it like this inside your `.dataTable({});` definition:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    {   "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
            if (type === 'filter') {
                return data.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Using type to know whether it is filter or display is awasome :)Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you please provide some jsfiddle link with the example.

Thanks in advance